# Convertir una expresión en sql server a función

Tags: sql-server

Trabajo con SQL Server 2008 R2 pretendo convertir una expresión que convierte de `string` a `int`

```
JOIN tabla ON     IsNumeric(Campo2) = 1
 and charindex('.', Campo2) = 0
 and charindex('.', Campo2) = 0
 and charindex('e', Campo2) = 0
 and charindex('E', Campo2) = 0
 and campo1 = cast(campo2 AS INT)
```

Pretendo crear una función con ese código algo como esto

```
CREATE FUNCTION TryCastInt(@value NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(
        ISNUMERIC(@value) = 1
    and charindex('.', @value) = 0
    and charindex('.', @value) = 0
    AND CHARINDEX('e', @value) = 0
    AND CHARINDEX('E', @value) = 0
    );
    
END
GO
```

No se como concluir se que tengo que poner el `return` pero no se como?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo valiéndote de una variable auxiliar, para con un `if` evaluar si cumple todas las condiciones y entonces realizar la conversión. Si no se reliza la conversión, la variable conservará `null`, que será el valor a retornar. En código luciría algo como:

```
create function TryCastInt(@value nvarchar(4000))
returns int
as
begin
  declare @result int;
  if      IsNumeric(@value) = 1
      and CharIndex('.', @value) = 0
      and CharIndex('.', @value) = 0
      and CharIndex('e', @value) = 0
      and CharIndex('E', @value) = 0
    set @result = cast(@value as int);
  return @result;  
end
go
```

Entonces la usarías así:

```
select dbo.TryCastInt('1'), dbo.TryCastInt('hola')
```

que retorna:

```
----------- -----------
1           NULL

(1 row affected)
```

O en la condición del join, así:

```
JOIN tabla ON campo1 = dbo.TryCastInt(campo2)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION TryCastInt(@value NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(
        SELECT cast(@value as int)
            WHERE
                 ISNUMERIC(@value) = 1
             and CHARINDEX('.', @value) = 0
             and CHARINDEX('.', @value) = 0
             AND CHARINDEX('e', @value) = 0
             AND CHARINDEX('E', @value) = 0
        );
    
END
```

Directamente puedes aplicar Select para que return sepa que devuelve un valor.

Comment: Dado que isNumeric no funciona realmente como parece, como por ejemplo para la entrada `IsNumeric('1d5')` o `IsNumeric('$15')`, que para ambos resultados devuelve 1 y no se tienen en cuenta estos en las expresiones a evaluar en el Where, esa función puede dar errores de conversión. [IsNumeric Isnt Is Number](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber)